# Eslint in reactjs project fixing warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have warning *Definition for rule 'react/state-in-constructor' was not foundeslint(react/state-in-constructor)*

Eslint version 6.8.0

Code in my file **.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    strict: 0,
    semi: 'error',
    'react/state-in-constructor': 1,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }]
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      createClass: 'createReactClass',
      pragma: 'React',
      version: 'detect',
      flowVersion: '0.53'
    },
    propWrapperFunctions: [
      'forbidExtraProps',
      { property: 'freeze', object: 'Object' },
      { property: 'myFavoriteWrapper' }
    ],
    linkComponents: ['Hyperlink', { name: 'Link', linkAttribute: 'to' }]
  }
};
```

Comment: can you post your package.json, seems like some dependencies are not installed.

Comment: you can see in [codepen](https://codepen.io/abbostajimov/pen/KKpYXVK)

Comment: update eslint-plugin-react to latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eslint-plugin-react` npm package needs to be updated for that feature to work.

Solve it by running `npm install eslint-plugin-react@latest`.

Or with yarn: `yarn add eslint-plugin-react@latest`